# Observe NSURL iCloud Property

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, icloud

Is there a way to observe changes of a NSURL iCloud Property like `NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying a `NSURL` for `NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey` does not work. You should use a `NSMetadataQuery` and `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should register for a notification like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector (iCloudAccountAvailabilityChanged:)
     name: NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification
     object: nil];
```

iCloudAccountAvailabilityChanged will be called whenever the iCloud status changes. At this place you also may re-query the URL to your ubiquity container.